# Why does em override p for font-family?

Tags: html, css, font-family

Consider the following CSS:

```css
* {  font-family: Gill Sans, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif}

p {  font-family: Courier; }
```

And then this markup:

```html
<p>Hi there. So <em>very</em> pleased to make your acquaintance.</p>
```

Why does the `<em>` display in Gill Sans? Or rather, why does the wildcard override the `<p>`. I guess I can see -some- logic in this if every tag has the same 'weight', but it still seems like a 'bug' to me intuitively... and it tends to make for more markup for me in that I can't assume that `<em>` will -only- affect the font-style in a particular way.

In short, is there a way to have 'modifiers' like `<em>` only operate on specific features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` matches *every* element, including the `<em>` inside the `<p>`.
The `<em>` would have inherited the font from the `<p>`, but the `*` overrides it.

You should almost never use `*`.
If you want to apply a global font, set it to `body`, so that other rules can override it for specific elements and cascade to their descendants.

Comment: Thanks. As I wrote, I guess that makes sense from one point of view, but somehow it still -feels- wrong. Good tip on the <body> idea!

Comment: No, the `em` element does *not* inherit `font-family`, because the element has `font-family` set on it.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: Clarified

Answer (score 1):

Assuming only the code presented, the only `font-family` declaration set on the `em` element is the one set for `*`, so it applies. It is then completely irrelevant what `font-family` may have been set on its parent.

The question “is there a way to have 'modifiers' like `<em>` only operate on specific features” does not make sense, because `<em>` is not a modifier and because CSS in general operates on specific features. So if you set a property on an `em` element, it will apply, unless there is another setting for the element that overrides it. In the given example, there is no conflict of settings: only one rule applies.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could modify your css and fix it:

```
p, p * {  font-family: Courier; }
```

or use `body` selector instead of `*`